# How to Get Thread Waitreasons using powershell?

Tags: powershell, thread-safety

Hi I have tried to get the Thread wait reason to monitor the threads. But unable to get the proper Reasons.

```
Get-Process -ProcessName NpService | Select-Object -ExpandProperty  Threads | Select-Object -Property ID ,  @{Label='WaitReasons';Expression={$.GetStatus(-Property WaitReason)}},  @{N='Current Date';E={ $(Get-Date -Format 'y-M-d H:mm:ss') }} , BasePriority , CurrentPriority , ThreadState , WaitReason , PriorityLevel , TotalProcessorTime , UserProcessorTime , PrivilegedProcessorTime  | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I was getting an output of Enum . But i need Enum string value. So i tried creating a Swtich statement but i dont know how to call it from the Select-Object

```
 class ThreadStatus {

[string]GetStatus($threadId) {
    Write-Output $threadId
$CustomObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
 $Wait_ReasonValue  =""

switch($threadId)
{
    "EventPairHigh" {return "Waiting for event pair high.Event pairs are used to communicate with protected subsystems." ; break}
        "EventPairLow" { return "Waiting for event pair low. Event pairs are used to communicate with protected subsystems." ; break}
        #ExecutionDelay { $Wait_ReasonValue = "Thread execution is delayed." ; break}
        #Executive { $Wait_ReasonValue = "The thread is waiting for the scheduler." ; break}
        #FreePage { $Wait_ReasonValue = "Waiting for a free virtual memory page." ; break}
        #LpcReceive { $Wait_ReasonValue = "Waiting for a local procedure call to arrive."; break}
        #LpcReply { $Wait_ReasonValue = "Waiting for reply to a local procedure call to arrive." ; break}
       # PageIn { $Wait_ReasonPropertyValue = "Waiting for a virtual memory page to arrive in memory." ; break}
        #PageOut { $Wait_ReasonValue = "Waiting for a virtual memory page to be written to disk." ; break}
      #  Suspended { $Wait_ReasonValue = "Thread execution is suspended." ; break}
       # SystemAllocation { $Wait_ReasonValue = "Waiting for a memory allocation for its stack." ; break}
        #Unknown { $Wait_ReasonValue = "Waiting for an unknown reason." ; break}
        #UserRequest { $Wait_ReasonValue = "The thread is waiting for a user request." ; break}
        #VirtualMemory { $Wait_ReasonValue = "Waiting for the system to allocate virtual memory." ; break}

        Default { $Wait_ReasonValue = " " ; break }
        }
         # $CustomObj | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "WaitReason" –Value $Wait_ReasonValue  
        # $CustomObj
        # Write-Output "TEST"
       # Write-Output $Wait_ReasonValue 
        return ""

            }
```

}
$tc = New-Object -TypeName ThreadStatus
$tc.GetStatus("EventPairHigdh")

I need to call the following method inside the Select-Object .

```
 $tc.GetStatus("EventPairHigh")
```

Output should be like this.

```
 Waiting for event pair high.Event pairs are used to communicate with protected subsystems.
```

When i tried the following code i am not getting the output for Process.

```
Get-Process -ProcessName Test | Select-Object @{Label='CMPNAME';Expression={$_.Name}}  -ExpandProperty Threads | Select-Object {$_.Id}

  OUTPUT :
         $_.Id
         -----
         8412
         10460
         10484
         10508
         10520
         10524
```

Comment: Add the `static` keyword before `[string]GetStatus` in the class definition, and then change `$.GetStatus` to `[ThreadStatus]::GetStatus` in the `Select-Object` property expression. Or drop the class definition and just do `@{Name='WaitReason';Expression={$_.WaitReason -as [string]}}`

Comment: @Mathias  : GetStatus has parameter to be passed that is property of thread   @{Label='WaitReasons';Expression={[ThreadStatus]::GetStatus(-Property WaitReason)}} .. I am getting error that i can't pass the parameter

Comment: `$_` refers to the current object in the pipeline, so you'll want to pass `$_.WaitReason` as the argument to the `GetStatus` param

Comment: I tried even hardcoding but not getting output Get-Process -ProcessName NpService | Select-Object -ExpandProperty  Threads | Select-Object @{Label='WaitReason';Expression={[ThreadStatus]::GetStatus("EventPairHigh")}}

Comment: You have `return ""` in the `GetStatus` method, so the result is _always_ going to be an empty string. Did you mean to `return $Wait_ReasonValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was getting an output of Enum . But i need Enum string value.

Luckily, enum values are easily converted to strings:

```
... | Select-Object -Property ID,@{Label='WaitReasons';Expression={$_.WaitReason -as [string]}}, ...
```

---

If you want to use a class method without tying it to an instance of the class, you need to mark it `static`:

```
class ThreadStatus {
  static [string] GetStatus([System.Diagnostics.ThreadWaitReason]$threadId){
    ...
  }
}

# Now we can invoke the method like this:
... | Select-Object -Property ID,@{Label='WaitReasons';Expression={[ThreadStatus]::GetStatus($_.WaitReason)}}, ...
```

Comment: Kindly check my question i have updated facing another issue with select-object

Comment: @AravindanSrinivasan Feel free to [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have another problem

Comment: Kindly check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920638/how-to-use-select-object-to-get-details-of-process-and-thread-in-single-query