# How to use Select-object to get details of process and thread in single query?

Tags: powershell, thread-safety, threadpool

when i executed the following query i am not getting the Name of the process only getting the thread details.

```
Get-Process -ProcessName Test | Select-Object @{Label='CMPNAME';Expression={$_.Name}}  -ExpandProperty Threads | Select-Object {$_.Id}

        OUTPUT :
                $_.Id
                -----
                8412
                10460
                10484
                10508
                10520
                10524
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `Select-Object` which properties to select:

```
Get-Process -ProcessName Test | Select-Object @{Label='CMPNAME';Expression={$_.Name}}  -ExpandProperty Threads | Select-Object CMPNAME,Id
```